# Connecting Hardware device buttons to SeekBar

Tags: android, button, hardware, volume, seekbar

How do I connect Hardware device buttons with Seek bar used for volume?
So every time I click on hardware buttons for example to increase volume, Seek Bar increase as well and vice verse

```
public void initControls()
{
    try
    {
        volumeSeekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        volumeSeekbar.setMax(audioManager
                .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
        volumeSeekbar.setProgress(audioManager
                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));   


        volumeSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) 
            {
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        progress, 0);
            }

        });

    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
@Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) 
     { 
            int index = seekbar1.getProgress(); 
            seekbar1.setProgress(index + 1); 
            return true; 
     } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
      {
            int index = seekbar1.getProgress(); 
            seekbar1.setProgress(index - 1); 
            return true; 
     }
      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
     }
```

Here is the edited code, I get error  The method onKeyDown (int, keyEvent)is undefined for the type object.

Comment: hey dude please write this code out of the current block....make seekbars global and access there value correspondingly...whay are you using key events in setOnSeekBarChangeListener..please write the code out side of this...write in such a way that they are parallel to lifecycle methods

Comment: public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
              // Your code here
              return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}

Comment: it should be inside main activity dude...

Comment: please write that code outside,...it will work

Comment: Hey dude, I did that and it gives me no errors in code, but when I use any hardware button on my phone, app crashes.
Here's logcat: http://prntscr.com/2i2nch

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
          if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) 
         { 
              mediaVlmSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
                int index = mediaVlmSeekBar.getProgress(); 
                mediaVlmSeekBar.setProgress(index + 1); 
                return true; 
         } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
          {
                int index = mediaVlmSeekBar.getProgress(); 
                mediaVlmSeekBar.setProgress(index - 1); 
                return true; 
         }
          return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
         }
```

Comment: Could you explain _why_ this answers the question?

Comment: When we Click on hardware button key VOLUME_UP or VOLUME_DOWN  call goes to onKeyDown Method and you can put your code in onKeyDown  for increase volume & Seek Bar increase as well and vice verse using KeyEvent

Answer (score 0):

By overriding the button input with something like this;

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{ 
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) { 
       // Do your thing 
       return true;
   } else {
       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
   }
}
```